# How can I print a certain block/part of a web page?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, printing, printscreen

How can I print a certain block/part of a web page?
Print option to look like Print Screen functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use css, with the media = print option.

Like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

The blocks you don't want printed can set display:none.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_print.cfm

You can use javascript's `window.print()` to print the page.  To restrict the printed content to a specific part of the page, you can create a print stylesheet (see http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) that hides all but the desired content.